# rxjs: keep infinite stream alive after error

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I wondering can I instead catchError in pipe of every foreign stream that is mergemaped in my infinite main stream, use one catchError in the end of my main stream. This catchError return a reference to main stream itself for rescue. It could cause memory leak or any other problems?

This is sample code:

```typescript
import { Observable, fromEvent } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, mergeMap } from "rxjs/operators";

function foreignStream() {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(0);
    observer.next(1);
    observer.next(2);
    observer.error("error");
  });
}

const stream$ = fromEvent(document, "click").pipe(
  mergeMap(foreignStream),
  catchError(x => {
    console.log(x);
    return stream$;
  })
);
stream$.subscribe(
  console.log,
  x => console.log("err" + x),
  () => console.log("complete")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the solution certainly looks interesting, it would actually lead to a new subscription on each error all the while the old subscriptions are left open. You could instead use `retry` or `retryWhen` to restart the source observable in case of an error.

Try the following

**RxJS `retry`**

```js
const stream$ = fromEvent(document, "click").pipe(
  mergeMap(foreignStream),
  mergeMap(foreignStream2),
  mergeMap(foreignStream3),
  retry() // <-- retry immediately infinite times
);
```

```js
const stream$ = fromEvent(document, "click").pipe(
  mergeMap(foreignStream),
  mergeMap(foreignStream2),
  mergeMap(foreignStream3),
  retry(5) // <-- retry immediately 5 times on errors and complete
);
```

**RxJS `retryWhen`**

```js
const stream$ = fromEvent(document, "click").pipe(
  mergeMap(foreignStream),
  mergeMap(foreignStream2),
  mergeMap(foreignStream3),
  retryWhen(error => error.pipe(delay(5000))) // <-- retry after 5 seconds infinite times
);
```

Comment: retry operator is definitely a better solution. I not suspected that it can be used without argument for infinite retry, but it is my oversight in reading documentation.
About returning a reference to main stream it is as you say. A quote from documentation: "a function that takes as arguments err, which is the error, and caught, which is the source observable, in case you'd like to "retry" that observable by returning it again."
Thanks for answer